# Get the value from a loop in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to get the loop variable from a loop. However, renderText function utilizes the last loop's value.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel("main panel",   textOutput("ts_txt1"), textOutput("ts_txt2"), textOutput("ts_txt3"), textOutput("ts_txt4"), textOutput("ts_txt5"), textOutput("ts_txt6"), textOutput("ts_txt7"), textOutput("ts_txt8"), textOutput("ts_txt9"), textOutput("ts_txt10"),)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({  
    for (i in 1:10) {
        output[[paste0("ts_txt",i)]]<- renderText(
        { paste0(i,"_" )})
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My desired output is as follow:

```
1_
2_
3_
4_
5_
6_
7_
8_
9_
10_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel("main panel",   textOutput("ts_txt1"), textOutput("ts_txt2"), textOutput("ts_txt3"), textOutput("ts_txt4"), textOutput("ts_txt5"), textOutput("ts_txt6"), textOutput("ts_txt7"), textOutput("ts_txt8"), textOutput("ts_txt9"), textOutput("ts_txt10"),)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({  
    for (i in 1:10) {
      local({
        i <- i
        output[[paste0("ts_txt",i)]]<- renderText({ paste0(i,"_" )})
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]